# COUNT () with some condition

Tags: oracle, count, conditional-statements

I have this table

```
noArticle QuantiteCommandee    

10        20
20         9
40         4
50         2
60
70         8
80
81
90         1
95         3
```

I want to count how many article have more than 5 in quantiy and less then 2

what i have right now :

```
/
SELECT COUNT ( case when QuantiteCommandee > 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PLUSQUE5,     
COUNT ( case when QuantiteCommandee < 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS PLUSPETITQUE2
From (SELECT Article.noArticle, SUM (quantite) AS QuantiteCommandee
FROM  Article
LEFT JOIN LigneCommande ON Article.noArticle = LigneCommande.noArticle
GROUP By ( Article.noArticle))
/
```

It returns me

```
 PLUSQUE2 PLUSQUE5
10    10
```

It doesnt seems like its seeing my condition > 5 and < 2

EDIT : The from table That you see is the table at the top i dont know what information i can give you more than that ?

SOLVED : REMOVE ELSE PART

Comment: Please give real table (full table specifications) otherwise it is difficult to help u.

Comment: EDIT ? does this help you better ?

Comment: just remove else part of each case, because now it counts both 1s and 0s for the count.

Comment: Seems to work ! Like a charm thank u dinidu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this-

```
SELECT
        COUNT ( case when QuantiteCommandee > 5 THEN 1 END)  AS PLUSQUE5,     
        COUNT ( case when QuantiteCommandee < 2 THEN 1 END ) AS PLUSPETITQUE2
    From    (
                SELECT
                        Article.noArticle, SUM (quantite) AS QuantiteCommandee
                    FROM  Article
                    LEFT JOIN LigneCommande ON Article.noArticle = LigneCommande.noArticle
                GROUP By (Article.noArticle)
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this query

```
select count(case when QuantiteCommandee>5 then 1 end) count_greaterthan_5,
count(case when QuantiteCommandee<2 then 1 end) count_lessthan_2 
from sandeep24feb_3;
```